# How can I subtract a year and add months to my dates?

Tags: javascript, date, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a column that contains future dates and I want to subtract year and add months using modified JavaScript step.

The datatype of `CloseDate` is `Date` and is in mm/dd/yyyy format. eg `01/10/2020`

I tried the following:

```
var newDate;
year(CloseDate) = year(CloseDate)-1;
month(CloseDate) = month(CloseDate)+5;
newDate = CloseDate;
```

But it is not modifying the date and I got following error:

```
Modified JavaScript value.0 - Javascript error: 
Modified JavaScript value.0 - ReferenceError: Function function year() {
    [native code, arity=1]
}
 can not be used as the left-hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator. (script#11)
```

Am I missing something in my JavaScript code?

Comment: Is `CloseDate` a string? If so what does it look like, could you provide an example

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be sure that all necessary functions and variables are declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CloseDate is already a `Date` field, in PDI's `Modified JavaScript Script Value Step`, you can use `dateAdd` function():

```
var newDate = dateAdd(dateAdd(CloseDate,"y",-1), "m", 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the new year and month to a valid variable:

```
var year = CloseDate.getFullYear()-1;
var month = CloseDate.getMonth()+5;
```

While we are at it, we should get the day, too:

```
var day = CloseDate.getDate();
```

Note that parentheses on the left hand side of an `=` doesn't make any sense and causes an error. Also, I am using the correct function names to get the parts of the date. These functions are in the `Date` prototype, so I must use dot notation to access them. I found these by googling for "javascript date" and then clicking the first link which is for the MDN documentation.

Finally, put the parts back together as a full date:

```
var newDate = new Date(year, month, day);
```